# Ошибка "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Делаю рекурсивную функцию для вывода меню с неопределенным числом предков и потомков.
Вот код:

```
<?

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("BD");

//$zapros=mysql_query("select * from test where id=0");
//echo ($zapros);

function menu($parent, $h)
{
    $h++;

    $zapros = mysql_query("select * from test where id={$parent}");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezult)) {
        echo "{$row['name']}<p>";

        $zapros1 = mysql_query("select * from test where key={$row['id']}");

        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($zapros1)) {
            echo " <p>{$row1['name']}<p>";
            $p = $row1['id'];
            menu($p, $h);

        }
    }
}
menu(0, 0);

?>
```

Таблица базы данных:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

В результате пишет мне:

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test.php on line 16`

Различные манипуляции ни к чему не приводят. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
$zapros = mysql_query("select * from test where id={$parent}");
```

У Вас:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezult)) {...
```

А надо:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($zapros)) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключение вида:

```
$Link = mysql_connect($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DBName, $Link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Не помогает. К базе подлючение хорошее, кажется в коде проблема...

Comment: 1) while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezult)) {

замените на:

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($zapros)) {

2) menu(0, 0);

замените на:

menu(11, 0);

т.к. Вы при создании таблицы указали: AUTO_INCREMENT=11

Answer (score 0):

В одном из циклов у вас, видимо, значение из `mysql_query()`возвращается в виде null: например, ошибка в запросе.

Answer (score 0):

ID неравен 0, попробуйте вызвать функцию, например menu(1, 0); если конечно записи у вас не начинаются с 11